# How to get rid of theme stealers?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, obfuscation

So basically I'm creating wordpress themes for Themeforest, and I would like to get rid of theme stealers. I need ideas how to do that, I have a plan, but I'm not sure what would be the best solution to realise it (to keep users away from removing it or atleast make it as hard as possible). The idea is like this, after installing theme, it adds a counter somewhere, and it says after x days your theme will be blocked if you won't enter purchase code. If they enter purchase code and it is valid (will validate with API), then notice about blocking will dissapear and script will be deleted, otherwise if they won't enter the purchase code theme will be blocked. I can do the blocking thing e.c., but I need a suggestion, how to make it as hard as possible for users to remove this feature? If I will add the line in one of the theme files, they will be able just to remove it.

So any suggestions?

Comment: I've added the `obfuscation` tag because you're asking how to make the code harder to modify. :)

Comment: Also please note that it's a bit "heavy" to make a theme that would do an external API call *on every page refresh*. You perhaps might be better off with a form of legal protection, as opposed to a technical one.

Comment: Could you please tell more about form of legal protection?

Comment: hack their server and format the hard-drives will be the most effective  (however not 100% legal) way!

Comment: There's one big problem with obfuscation in WP themes: the "bad guys" do it a lot. There are lots of "free" scam templates, that will secretly add spam links to your website, and worse. So professional admins will check your theme for obfuscated code (there are tools that do these checks automatically) before they use it. You might actually hurt your user base doing this. http://wpmu.org/why-you-should-never-search-for-free-wordpress-themes-in-google-or-anywhere-else/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because WP-templates are opensource, there is no way to do this. No matter what you do, they will also be able to open the exact same file and undo anything you did. In addition, it is more difficult to block something than removing it.

You could try to base64 encode it, but again, they will be able to undo whatever you do.

I am not a fan og WP and I don't have much experience with it; BUT, I would suggest to set up a demo-site with each template. If people need to be able to "test" the admin-interface, set up a mod where you remove all the template-settings, so they can't get a hold of the files.

Long story short; when opensource-files are moved away from a closed environment to their own, you loose all kind of control.

Comment: Well, basically I want to make it as hard as possible for them. So atleast stelaers who publish the theme on free pages, would have to edit something.

Comment: Well, kind of depends how difficult you want to do it, but you could hide your function within other functions and make some sort of code-soup that looks like something else, or looks like rubbish to confuse the users. Again, everyone with some experience with PHP would always be able to remove it. + this is not a good way to treat the people that use it, because you would have to connect to some sort of authentication-site on your server at every load or something.

Comment: Well, hmm, lets say, it will do a check only once per day, and when you login in the admin panel.

Comment: You don't seem to grasp the nature of "open" source. As @OptimusCrime has said, any developer with a modicum of knowledge will be able to rip out that check.